# Justification of the caption of a wrapfigure

Tags: captions, wrapfigure

I am trying to center the caption of a figure in latex.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.50 \textwidth}
  \vspace{-20pt}
  \begin{center}
    \resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{ \subimport{./Figures/}{vector.tex}}
  \vspace{-10pt}
   \captionsetup{margin=1.8cm}
  \caption{Graphic representation of vectors}
  \label{fig:vectors}
    \end{center}
  \vspace{-10pt}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

and my figure is done in another file as follows

```
\documentclass[float=false, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thin,gray!40] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
  \draw[line width=2pt,blue,-stealth](0,0)--(1,1) node[anchor=south west]{$\boldsymbol{}$};
  \draw[line width=2pt,red,-stealth](-2,0)--(-1,1) node[anchor=south west]{$\boldsymbol{}$};
  \draw[line width=2pt,green,-stealth](-1,-1)--(-2,-2) node[anchor=north east]{$\boldsymbol{}$};
  \draw[line width=2pt,magenta,-stealth](2,0)--(1,-1) node[anchor=north east]{$\boldsymbol{}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: I get this]

I would like to have the caption center and the figure a little bit larger so the figure is larger of the caption. I also would like that the text continues around the figure and not only in the left part of the figure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum [2]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.50 \textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}% image you can insert with \input{<path>/<file name>}
    [scale=1.2,% increased image
    L/.style = {draw=#1, line width=2pt,-stealth}% for simplified imnage code
    ]
  \draw[thin,gray!40] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
  \draw[L=blue]     ( 0,0)  -- ( 1,1);
  \draw[L=red]      (-2,0)  -- (-1,1);
  \draw[L=green]    (-1,-1) -- (-2,-2);
  \draw[L=magenta]  (2,0)   -- (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
   \captionsetup{margin=1.2cm}
  \caption{Graphic representation of vectors}
  \label{fig:vectors}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

note: `tikzpicture` as `tex` file can not be scaled by `\resizebox`. if you like increase it size, you should use `scale` in image code or include image as pdf file and than use `includegraphics[width=<length>]{<path>/<image name>}`.

or you mean to have caption in centering justification?

[image]

for above caption i use

```
\captionsetup{margin=1cm,justification=centering}
```